# Command scripts in Play 1.2.x

Tags: configuration, playframework, playframework-1.x

In Play 1.2.x, how can I can create global command scripts?

I would like to achieve something like "play setup", which internally does many things:
checks (and modifies) the configuration file for particular properties
clones some additional stuff from GIT, or does some other copy/move housekeeping
runs "play deps"

I saw that it is possible to create custom commands in modules, but I'd like to have something that is distributed with the application itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: Distributed with a play application or with play itself?

Comment: with a play application

Answer (score 0):

If add custom commands to a module, they will apply to any application you include them in. So if you have commands in module `Core` and you have an application called `MyApp` with a dependency on `Core`, those commands will show up if you run `play help` on `MyApp`.

Adding custom commands to an application itself directly is not supported (although you could always hack it in if it's only for local use).